# How to implate a led animation like this?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am try to build a led animation with javascript. Bug currently I am able to get it like this: http://jsbin.com/esakip/1/

animation parten:

```
*___*___*___*___*___*___*___*___*___*___*___*___*___*___
```

It display every 400ms, I want it switch like this for example:

switch on/off 3 times, then sleep 1 second, then do this process again.

```
*_*_*______*_*_*______*_*_*______*_*_*______*_*_*______
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it configurable:

```
var pattern=('*_*_*______').split('');

function showNext(lastIndex){
    var nextIndex = lastIndex+1;
    // go back to the start if we are past the end
    nextIndex = nextIndex % pattern.length;
    // do we need to do anything?
    if(pattern[lastIndex] != pattern[nextIndex]){
        //fade in or out depending on the current symbol
        if(pattern[nextIndex]=='*'){
            $('#led').fadeIn('fast');
        }else{
            $('#led').fadeOut('fast');
        }
    }
    // call this function again after a pause
    setTimeout(function(){showNext(nextIndex);},400);
}
// start the thing off
showNext(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do this:

```
while (true)
$('#led').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').delay('1000');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while crashes the browser... If you need to loop this animation, put it inside a function and recall it again and again..

```
$(function (){
  setInterval(function(){

    $('#led').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').delay('1000');

  },1800);
});
```

Updated http://jsfiddle.net/kvJsc/5/

Comment: Thanks for your example.But how to make this animation spped configurable?In your example, it switch 2 times in one second. If I want to flash 3 times. I must change code to:
$('#led').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').delay('1000');

Comment: You just have to sum up the animation times. Fast is 200 ms so the 1800 ms for the interval come from 200 + 200 + 200 + 200 + 1000 ms = 1800.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvJsc/6/

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery :

`$('#led').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').delay('1000').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast').delay('1000');`
...

http://jsfiddle.net/kvJsc/